# Uniswap import results in compiler error

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I need some help, i am getting a error messages when i import [Quoter](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol) from uniswap and compile it:

`import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol";`

I commented the rest of my code out and i still get the same error.
Other import from uniswap work like:

```
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
```

Any ideas?

```
TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int24" to "uint256".
  --> @uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol:25:28:
   |
25 |         require(absTick <= uint256(MAX_TICK), 'T');
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "address".
  --> @uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/PoolAddress.sol:35:16:
   |
35 |         pool = address(
   |                ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Comment: What solidity version are you using? If I remember correctly newer solc versions don't allow casting between uintXX and intXX.

Comment: The solidity version was the issue. I had 2 different ones specified in my hardhat config. Thank you!

Comment: which versions did you use @DarjuschSchrand, can you please post your config as the answer