# How to use UniSwap's TWAP with solidity version ^0.8

Tags: solidity, uniswap, solidity-0.8.x, uniswapv3

I'm trying to use UniswapV3's OracleLibrary for an on-chain price feed. I am using solidity version ^0.8 throughout my project but the OracleLibrary is incompatible with the breaking changes of 0.8.
I have mitigated some of the issues like this one:  [TypeCastingIssue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122296/uniswap-import-results-in-compiler-error).

But it still errors in places:

```
arithmeticMeanTick = int24(tickCumulativesDelta / secondsAgo);
if (tickCumulativesDelta < 0 && (tickCumulativesDelta % secondsAgo != 0))arithmeticMeanTick--;
```

[image]

[image]

Can somebody help me tackle these errors? Any and all help is appreciated :)

P.S. I can't downgrade the solidity version of other contracts as I'm using some of the new features throughout the project.